# Yii: What is signature of behaviors?

Tags: php, yii, yii-components

what is signature of behaviors in yii? should this be a function or a class method? 
Can any provide sample code?

Comment: Are you looking for a specific signature, or a general definition of method signatures?

Comment: @RobertHarvey specific signature.

Comment: You didn't find it here? http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/44/behaviors-events/

Comment: @RobertHarvey Can't we add single method of class or simple function as a behavior to the component?

Comment: Why not use [Traits](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php)?

Comment: @Traits how do I use function as behavior?

Comment: Behaviors works somewhat like PHP 5.4 traits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no signature for behaviors, as behaviors are intented to add *some* function to class. Only requirement is to extend from `CBehavior`. [Like in wiki](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/44/behaviors-events/) or [docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.component#component-behavior):

```
class SomeClass extends CBehavior
{
    public function add($x, $y) { return $x + $y; }
}

class Test extends CComponent
{
    public $blah;
}

$test = new Test(); 
// Attach behavior
$test->attachbehavior('blah', new SomeClass);

// Now you can call `add` on class Test
$test->add(2, 5);
```

However since PHP 5.4 you can use [Traits](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php) which are **native** php implementation and have a lot more features, example above with traits:

```
// NOTE: No need to extend from any base class
trait SomeClass
{
    public function add($x, $y) { return $x + $y; }
}

class Test extends CComponent
{
    // Will additionally use methods and properties from SomeClass
    use SomeClass;
    public $blah;
}

$test = new Test(); 
// You can call `add` on class Test because of `use SomeClass;`
$test->add(2, 5);
```

There are [a lot more features with traits](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php)